# Why is this http server described as leaking?

Tags: node.js, memory-leaks

[This](https://www.nearform.com/blog/how-to-self-detect-a-memory-leak-in-node/) web site describes the http server implementation below in a post about memory leaks. What's wrong with it?

```
const http = require('http');

var server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
 for (var i=0; i<1000; i++) {
 server.on('request', function leakyfunc() {});
 }

 res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
server.setMaxListeners(0);

console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/. Process PID: ', process.pid);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`http.createServer` returns an object of type `http.Server` which extends the `EventEmitter` [class](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_class_eventemitter). Now, an `EventEmitter` allows to attach listeners to it, which will be executed once the corresponding `event` is triggered (in this case when the http-server receives a request).

In your case you attach `1000` ***additional*** listeners to the http-server on every request, that will execute `leakyfunc()` each. So you potentially have a huge number of listeners that need to be executed on each request and that will eventually eat up your heap memory.